# Excel Merge three columns into one with leaving empty cells blank

Tags: excel

Hello i need to do the following thing in excel but i am completely new to it and i find myself at a loss.

I need to take the value of J1 which is text, the values of the column `K:K`

and the value of `L1` and merge them in the column `F:F`.

Usually this would be made with =$J$1&K:K&$L$1 however the column K:K have a lot of empty cells which have to be left empty in column `F:F` as well but right now the empty cells return the value of `J1&L1`.

I am sure this could be made with some if statement but i can formulate it :(

Comment: In other words, if `K1` is empty you want to display no text in `F1`, otherwise you want to display `=$J$1&$K1&$L$1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF($K1="","",$J$1&$K1&$L$1)
```

And drag it down.

Comment: Try replacing `,` with `;` (it may depend on your regional settings).

Comment: ahh yes that was it when i replaced , with ; it worked like a charm thanks mate :)